# How do I loop through all values in a dictionary if the values are dates

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I want to calcualte days between certain amount of dates and today but I have a lot of dates that I've put in a dictionary and can't seem to loop through them.

```
from datetime import date

dates= {"A": (2019, 7, 25), "B": (2017, 1, 19), "C": (2016, 11, 17), "D": (2017, 10, 17)}    
current = date(2019, 7, 24)

for key, value in champs.items():
    d1 = date(champs[value])
    days = d1 - current
    print(days)
```

I tried this but it gives me this error :

```
KeyError: (2019, 7, 24)
```

I want to know how many days are there between each date in the dictionary and the current date. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `for key, value in champs.items():` here value is the date tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `d1 = date(*value)`. You already get the (key and) value from dict since you use `items()` method.

A bit better solution would be to either not use a dict (as you don't do anything with keys), or, as below, to directly iterate over values.

```
from datetime import date

dates = {
    "A": (2019, 7, 25),
    "B": (2017, 1, 19),
    "C": (2016, 11, 17),
    "D": (2017, 10, 17),
}

current = date(2019, 7, 24)

for date_tuple in dates.values():
    d1 = date(*date_tuple)
    delta = current - d1
    print(delta.days)
```

Output

```
-1
916
979
645
```